# WordPress: Redirect post after deleting it in the admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm using a function which I built to delete all posts from a user after a specific post from the user is deleted. In my case I'm using a Custom Post Type called "company". And additional Custom Post Types like "jobs" or "events". If the company post gets deleted, all other posts from this user are also deleted.

What I don't know to solve is how I add a safe 301 redirect to the old posts. The company post and to all additional posts.

Here is my code I'm using so far:

```
function delete_all_posts_from_author($post_id) {


    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;

    // Only trigger if post type is "company"
    if ( get_post_type($id) == "company" ) {

        $author_id = $post->post_author;

        $posts_from_author = get_posts(
            array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'post_type'         => array('event','job'),
                'author'            => $author_id,
                'fields'            => 'ids', // Only get post ID's
            )
        );

        foreach ( $posts_from_author as $post_from_author ) {
            wp_delete_post( $post_from_author, false); // Set to False if you want to send them to Trash.
        }
    }


}

add_action( 'publish_to_trash',  'delete_all_posts_from_author', 10, 1 );
```

I've tried to add the following line before "wp_delete_post":

```
wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
```

But without success.

Is there an other way to do this?

Comment: You could use a plugin like Redirection and add redirects using their API.

If you're doing it yourself, you need to store the redirects somewhere and hook into pre_get_posts to do the redirect before WP starts working on the URL and sends a 404.

Comment: thanks for the top but I would prefer to not using a plugin ;)